# Angular - Filtering a list where { Item.user.id : something }

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I have a list of "Savings" in an ng-repeat. The model for savings is

```
    var SavingSchema = new Schema({

  title: {
    type: String,
  },
  link: {
    type: String,
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }

});
```

Therefore i need to get to saving.user._id

Im trying something like

```
<div ng-repeat="saving in savings|filter:{ 'user._id': 'otherid' }">
```

but it doesnt like the `user._id`

Works fine with `._id` if i want to filter by the top level `_id` but not the embedded `user._id`

How do i filter by the embedded `user._id` as the left side parameter

Comment: You could do a ng-show div below this?

Comment: Why are you asking for `user._id`? The data would only be returned as a single `ObjectId` value to "user". Unless you were calling mongoose `.populate()` when returning the data. Which you probably are not, given the question.

Comment: I am creating a user profile page so i need that particular users list of "savings". I have a list of savings each with an embedded user object value each with an id that i want to match with the profile page. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I think you are missing the point here. If you have not called `.populate()` ( and that would be advised in this case, since you only want the `_id` value that is already there ) then your data for "user" would look like `"user": "56b80b28ef6ad334814944cf"`. Only with `.populate()` to resolve the reference would it look something like `"user": { "_id": "56b80b28ef6ad334814944cf", "name": "Fred" }`. So unless you did that, you are then trying to filter on something that does not exist.

Comment: Yeah theres definitely something im misunderstanding alright. If you look at this screenshot it might be easier to understand what i want to do. I want to filter by the highlighted _id. You can see the unfiltered list is all the "savings" http://i.imgur.com/L6p87kA.png

Comment: SHow us sample of exactly what is sent to browser and stored in `$scope.savings`, not back end schema. Can copy right from browser dev tools network and find actual request

Comment: I assume this is what is sent to browser http://i.imgur.com/L6p87kA.png Is that correct?

Comment: Create a custom angular filter. Easy to put together

Comment: Can you even just write the comparison so i know? What should this be? { 'user._id': 'otherid' }

Comment: Hi, in your example you have to use filter in the js controller as function

Comment: Thanks. The only thing im not sure is how to grab the userID of the profile page. The "http://localhost:3000/users/56a1832a36dc3d0e00c7aa3f". This isnt the logged in user but the owner of the profile page. Not sure how to get at that value.